# How can I get information about store users in BigCommerce?

Tags: bigcommerce

I would like to retrieve information about the currently logged in user, and whether that user is also a store admin console user. I need to provide additional user-interfaces to supplement the current admin (editing Customer Attributes), and I'm trying to figure out the best way to do Role Based Access.

For example: Shopify provides the User api https://help.shopify.com/en/api/reference/plus/user that provides these endpoints

```
GET /admin/api/2019-04/users.json
Retrieves a list of all users
GET /admin/api/2019-04/users/#{user_id}.json
Retrieves a single user
```

Does this exist in BigCommerce in any way?

It appears the only way I can determine what role the user has is via the Load request in a marketplace application. https://developer.bigcommerce.com/api-docs/getting-started/building-apps-bigcommerce/building-apps#building-apps_processing-signed-payload

> **Request Type** = Load
>
> **Multiple users enabled**
>
> Compare the user information to see if it matches that of the store owner, received at the time of app installation or that of an existing user. If the user information does not match either of these, then it represents a new user that you should add to your database or other storage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're correct--the app Load response will tell you whether the user activating the app is the store owner or another user role, but there isn't an API endpoint to request control panel users' permissions. On the client-side, that info is encrypted. The app Load response will be your best bet for making the distinction programmatically.

Comment: It will be an AWESOME day when BigCommerce has every API shopify does, and more...